# Replacing CoreNFC UI in readerSession?

Tags: swift, applepay, ndef, core-nfc

[image]

Is it possible to open an NFCReaderSession or NFCNDEFReaderSession, making tags readable in app using CoreNFC framework WITHOUT opening the bottom modal session?

I want to use the functionality of CoreNFC but I would essentially like to design the user interface differently.

So instead of this...

`self.nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession.init(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
self.nfcSession?.alertMessage = "message"
self.nfcSession?.begin()`

I would like to inherit the functionality without the UI that opens with this `self.nfcSession?.begin()`

Here is an image of an obvious example of what I would like to happen. When a user opens a view, I would like the session to begin without the clunky bottom modal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible. You can set a message or an alert message. That's all.